# Three-tier architecture system with Android clients without REST

Tags: java, android, rest, jboss, three-tier

I want to create web-based application which interacts with Android clients. Clients are using non reliable connection thru EDGE/GPRS, with very limited amount of transfer, so I wanted to avoid using REST with all this HTTP protocol overhead. I've already created such project in Java, where Android clients talk JSON to server through sockets , and I wanted to port my app into a three-tier architecture - is it possible to achieve the same results with some kind of application server: JBoss or Glassfish?

Comment: HTTP isn't all that bad (especially if you GZip) but if you're that concerned, you shouldn't be using JSON. That's probably a way bigger overhead than HTTP is.

Comment: I've been thinking about some very very simple protocol like command and parameter, JSON only to use some content standard just to transfer these between server and clients.